# How to disable multiple objects selected in outliner?

Tags: outliner

My questions are :

1. In outliner i selected list of objects and want to disable/enable them (turn on/off monitor icon). How can i do this ? 'ALT' doesn't work for multiple on this case.
2. can i attach shortcut to switch this disable/enable ? when i right click the monitor icon, there's no option to add shortcut.

Thanks

Comment: Afaik, there is no operator for that, so no shortcut. Open Python console, type "bpy.ops.outliner." use tab key to have the possible operator list. You will find "hide" but this is the eye icon.

Comment: There's 'hide_viewport' operator to enable/disable monitor icon -> bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_viewport =1 , but it will work only If i can get the list of selected objects in outiner so i can then iterate the list. It's just i can't find API for getting selected objects in outliner.

Comment: Well, always the same question in fact. But again, I don't think such api exists for now.

Comment: ok, Thanks a lot for sharing.